# How do I refresh MFC dialog before Sleep() call

Tags: c++, mfc

I have an array of buttons holding bitmap images.
I'm trying to change the image of one of the buttons to a different image for one second, and then change it again - but during the sleep, the UI still displays the older image as if I hadn't changed it - this means I don't see `bmp_explosion` displayed at all.

```
void COOPFinalDlg::ShowExplosion(int position)
{
    SetButtonImage(position, bmp_explosion);
    Sleep(1000);
    SetButtonImage(position, bmp_tile);
}

void COOPFinalDlg::SetButtonImage(int buttonId, int imageId)
{
    CButton* button = buttons[buttonId - ButtonRangeStart];
    CBitmap bmp;
    bmp.LoadBitmap(imageId);
    button->SetBitmap(bmp);
}
```

The buttons were initalized to a bitmap the following way:

```
CBitmap bmp;
bmp.LoadBitmap(bmp_tile);
CRect rect(....);
CButton* button = new CButton;
button->Create(NULL, WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_TABSTOP | BS_PUSHBUTTON | DT_CENTER | WS_BORDER, rect, this, idCounter++);
button->ModifyStyle(0, BS_BITMAP);
button->SetBitmap(bmp);
buttons.Add(button);
```

Comment: When you call `Sleep()` your program does exactly that, it goes to sleep. Nothing happens until the sleep is done. The code after the sleep does *not* run until after the sleep time is up.  Using a sleep is *very rarely* the correct solution, you probably want to come up with some other solution.

Comment: My issue that the change I made before Sleep() was called isn't displayed. Sleep in this case is exactly the behavior I want - freeze the UI for one second, don't do anything and don't let the user touch anything

Comment: MFC applications are single-threaded, with an event-loop handling all events needed to handle *all* GUI events, including updating and redrawing it. If the event loop doesn't run (like what happens when you call `Sleep`) then nothing will happen with your UI. You need to come up with another way of simulating "sleep" (like *timers*).

Comment: I've just run a 'sort of' emulation of your problem and adding the equivalent of `button->RedrawWindow();` after the `button->SetBitmap(bmp);` call worked for me ... but I **won't** say that will *always* work. You could also put the calls to `RedrawWindow()` in the function just before and after the `Sleep()` call.

Comment: You probably want to use SetTimer(...) to post messages to your app every second. Sleep, like said, will cause your entire application to become unresponsive.

Comment: [RedrawWindow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-redrawwindow) can repaint a window without requiring a message loop. Though `Sleep` doesn't do what you think/need. It doesn't prevent user input, it merely delays input handling. If you really want to inhibit input, you're going to have to disable the window.

Comment: Thanks IInspectable and Adrian Mole, RedrawWindow worked great. In my case delaying user input is also acceptable. If you want to go ahead and post it as an answer I'll accept it and close the question

Comment: It's not just user input that is delayed - it's ALL WINDOW MESSAGEs are delayed (your message loop does not run).  That means any mouse clicks, any button hovering other GUI explosions, closing the app, etc.  Set up a timer and a little "explosion" state machine and you can get some pretty clever animation with a few timer events being fired (e.g. start small, medium, larger, add some smoke, add a mushroom cloud, etc., those would be the names of your 5 or 6 states, with a timer event firing every 500ms or so to update the image and move to the next state).  Your GUI remains responsive.

Comment: That a great idea franji but it's too time consuming.. This is an educational project for me, and doesn't have a real-world application :)